# How to "remove" Array elements or ge Range from uint8_t Array?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, arrays, uint8t

In my Iphone App I've an TCP Connection and want recive data which works ok.

But I need to split an uint8_t Array.

```
unsigned result;
uint8_t buffer[1024];
len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
NSString *hexstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02x%02x%02x%02x",buffer[3],buffer[2],buffer[1],buffer[0]];
                        result = 0;
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:hexstring];
[scanner scanHexInt:&result];
NSLog(@"HexString: %@ Result: %i ",hexstring,result);
NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Here I get the first 4 bytes to get the length of the recived package.

Now I want an output for the range of the buffer Array without buffer[1] - buffer[3]

I mean the Range from buffer[4] to buffer[length of packe].

How can I archive that?

Comment: My problem is that I have no idea how to remove elements from the uint8_t array since it isn't configurable like an NSMutableArray f.e.

Comment: You'd do it the same way you'd do it in plain old C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think the basic problem here is your use of a `uint8_t` array. As a C array, you should have a really compelling reason to use it in Objective-C. You don't have a compelling reason, here, and have identified a reason **not** to use it.

Instead of this:

```
uint8_t buffer[1024];
```

Use a `NSMutableData` built with `dataWithCapacity:`. Something like this:

```
NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:1024];
uint8_t *buffer = [data mutableBytes];
```

You can manipulate the data, then, with methods against `data`.

Alternately, you could use `memmove` (not `memcopy`) to manipulate your array directly. I don't think it's worth it, though; you can generally assume that Foundation will pick a good algorithm, whereas you're likely to pick the simplest, and you're more likely to introduce a block overrun.

Comment: One question concerning that: When I Log sizeof(buffer) from the uint8_t buffer[1024] example I get a value of 1024, but when I try sizeof(buffer) from uint8_t *buffer = [data mutableBytes] I only get a value of 4?

Comment: That's because the compiler knows how big `uint8_t buffer[1024]` is (because it had to make room for it on the stack) but doesn't know how big an arbitrary pointer (i.e. what you get back from `[data mutableBytes]`) is. You can call `[data length]` to get the size of an NSMutableData. You might consider spending some time reading up on basic C pointers, stack vs. heap, etc. 'cause it's pretty clear you're *totally* feeling around in the dark here.

Comment: The capacity argument to `-[NSMutableData initWithCapacity:]` is just a "hint", the memory is not necessarily allocated based on that value. Furthermore, there is no property/getter for `capacity` on an NSMutableData, so you can't read it back out. `length` is what you want. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableData_Class/Reference/NSMutableData.html Setting the length of an NSMutableData either truncates it or extends it.

Comment: You're right, my bad. No idea what I was looking at. I'll remove my comment.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: buffer + 4 length: len - 4 encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Pointer arithmetic for the win.

Also, getting a 32 bit `unsigned int` from 4 bytes by going through `NSString` is pretty circuitous (not to mention slow). Why not just do this:

```
uint32_t result = buffer[3] << 24 |  buffer[2] << 16 | buffer[1] << 8 | buffer[0];
```

I mean, even that is circuitous, but at least it's explicit, and doesn't assume the endianness of the host, and doesn't round trip through a string and an `NSScanner`.